# Map Dictionary to SwiftUI Collapsible List

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

In my SwiftUI-based app, I have a dictionary mapping arrays of Strings to Strings:

```
let featuresByVersion: [String : [String]] = [
    "1.2" : [
        "A new feature in this version",
        "Another new feature in this version.",
        "Etc.",
    ],
    "1.1" : [
        "A new feature in this version.",
        "Etc.",
    ],
]
```

I would like to display this data **in a collapsible List, using the "children" parameter**, such as:

```
List(<versions>, children: <features>) { row in
    //Text of each new feature in a particular version
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, you have to use a model. A `Dictionary` isn't and random access collection and turning it into an array makes the dictionary a tuple that hides `value` which is needed for `children`